# NGINX + CentOS 8 mydomain.com shows NGINX welcome page whereas mydomain.com/index.html shows website index page

Tags: nginx, ssl, centos8

I'm trying to configure NGINX on CentOS 8 (with SSL). I believe I have configured it properly, but I can't get rid of the NGINX welcome page. I've tried a lot of things, even deleted the entire `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory, but I still get NGINX welcome on `example.com`, whereas `example.com/index.html` gives me the index page of my website. In fact I have noticed that the http to https and non-www to www redirections I have implemented below don't work on `example.com`, but do work on `example.com/index.html`. The root of my website is `/var/www/example.com/html`. The configure file which is given below is called `example.com.conf` and located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

```
server {

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on default_server; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl default_server; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
# Redirect non-SSL to SSL
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name .example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect non-www to www
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you need to edit the global configuration file using `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and comment out "default_server" in the listen statements. Alternatively deleting the whole server block in the global conf file also works, as long as you keep the include statement which reads the example.com.conf file.

```
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80; # default_server;
        listen       [::]:80; # default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```